# How do I find out which IP addresses are being blocked by AWS security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Is there a way to determine which IP addresses are trying to access my AWS instances through an ELB security group? I'd like to know which ones are failing, because some of them will be from another cloud service I am using and so I want to allow them. It is not possible to find out the outbound addresses from the source system (the admin there is considering my request). I tried setting up access logs for an ELB, because the documentation suggests that will tell me, but it only shows successful access, not blocked access.

Comment: You can have a look at VPC flow logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup VPC access logs in which your ELB is present. You will be able to see source IP and destination IP. Filter out the records in which destination IP is same as your ELB IP. Compare it with ELB access logs. You will be able to see which IPs got blocked
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html